# How to fetch Json string from Database and assign it to grid view row textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, jsonconvert

I have dynamic grid row textboxes, i add values and save, it gets serialized into json format and gets saved in database, now when i have to populate the grid(when i refresh)the saved data needs to be displayed on the textboxes.
My code:

```
  foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtKey = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtKey");
                TextBox txtValue  = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue");


                string JsonDeserialize = dtTerminalLocalConfig.Rows[0]["Settings"].ToString();



                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> configurations = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

                configurations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(JsonDeserialize);

                configurations.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtKey.Text, txtValue.text));

                txtKey.Text  = configurations.SingleOrDefault(K => K.Key == LocalConfigurations.Key).Value;

               txtValue.Text = configurations.SingleOrDefault(K => K.Key == LocalConfigurations.Value).Value;

            }
```

The 'configuration' has deserialized json strings and is assigned to txtboxes, but the textbox are giving null when debugged

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] ([as text, not as a screen shot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) showing the JSON value of  `JsonDeserialize` that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  You have included the code, we just need to see the JSON to understand why it is not deserializing your ` List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a code review.

So, here are a few questions and answers:

Why is this chunk inside the `foreach` loop? Do you genuinely need to do this for every row, or just once?

```
string JsonDeserialize = dtTerminalLocalConfig.Rows[0]["Settings"].ToString();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> configurations = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
configurations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(JsonDeserialize);
```

(You can roll those last two statements into a single line btw:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> configurations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(JsonDeserialize);
```

What is this line doing?:

```
configurations.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtKey.Text, txtValue.text));
```

Why in your Linq statements are you only getting the key `== LocalConfigurations.Key`? That looks like it exists outside of the `foreach` loop, and so would populate each row with the same key/value pair.

Why are you getting a `KeyValuePair` twice with Linq?

Should the first line be setting txt**Key**.Text to .**Value**?

Should the second line be K => K.**Key** == LocalConfigurations.**Value** ?
Why Not:

```
KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp = configurations.SingleOrDefault(K => K.Key == LocalConfigurations.Key);
txtKey.Text  = kvp.Key;
txtValue.Text = kvp.Value;
```

Although if these are genuinely **Key**ValuePairs (i.e. the keys are unique), Why not deserialise to a `Dictionary<string,string>`? This would allow you to do something like:

```
string JsonDeserialize = dtTerminalLocalConfig.Rows[0]["Settings"].ToString();
Dictionary<string, string>> configurations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>>(JsonDeserialize);
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtKey = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtKey");
        TextBox txtValue  = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtValue");
        if(!configurations.TryGetValue(key), out string value) continue;
        txtKey.Text  = key;
        txtValue.Text = value;
    }
```

Hopefully this helps somewhat.